# JavaScript setInterval and `this` solution

Tags: javascript, this, setinterval

I need to access `this` from my `setInterval` handler

```
prefs: null,
startup : function()
    {
        // init prefs
        ...
        this.retrieve_rate();
        this.intervalID = setInterval(this.retrieve_rate, this.INTERVAL);
    },

retrieve_rate : function()
    {
        var ajax = null;
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open('GET', 'http://xyz.example', true);
        ajax.onload = function()
        {
            // access prefs here
        }
    }
```

How can I access `this.prefs` in `ajax.onload`?

Comment: to see a good answer with 3 solutions check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7890978/2803565

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The setInterval line should look like this:-

```
 this.intervalID = setInterval(
     (function(self) {         //Self-executing func which takes 'this' as self
         return function() {   //Return a function in the context of 'self'
             self.retrieve_rate(); //Thing you wanted to run as non-window 'this'
         }
     })(this),
     this.INTERVAL     //normal interval, 'this' scope not impacted here.
 );
```

**Edit**: The same principle applies to the " `onload` ". In this case its common for the "outer" code to do little, it just sets up the request an then sends it. In this case the extra overhead an additinal function as in the above code is unnecessary. Your retrieve_rate should look more like this:-

```
retrieve_rate : function()
{
    var self = this;
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('GET', 'http://xyz.example', true);
    ajax.onreadystatechanged= function()
    {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200)
        {
            // prefs available as self.prefs
        }
    }
    ajax.send(null);
}
```

Comment: I was going to do this initially, but then I remembered this pattern is really most useful for loops.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: It just as useful for this scenario as it is for loops.

Comment: @Anthony: so the trick with `self` is the only option here? can you confirm that the solution by Matthew will not work?

Comment: @Michael:  First of all its not a "trick" its just how things work in Javascript.  Matthew's answer as it currently stands at time of writing this comment doesn't work.  There was an earlier version of it that might have worked but it involved passing `this` as a parameter which was unnecessary and awkard (any caller of `retrieve_rate` would have know this unnecessary special requirement).

Comment: passing `this` as an argument to the `(function(self){...})(this)` in setInterval didn't work for me because the function is executed immediately instead of being delayed.  @Joel Fillmore's solution works for me

Comment: I wish I had known about this 12 hours ago. Going to permanently etch it into my brain now. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org), you could use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) which does this for you: `this.intervalID = setInterval(_.bind(this.retrieve_rate, this), this.INTERVAL);`

Comment: That's a lot of brackets over there

Comment: Why you didn't do in first code snippet same as second code: store the `this` ref in a local var as `var self = this;` and simply use that in `setInterval` ?

Answer (score 110):

```
this.intervalID = setInterval(this.retrieve_rate.bind(this), this.INTERVAL);
```

Comment: This is the right solution. The accepted solution seems to require unnecessarily more code.

Comment: But this method has a drawback. Most likely, it will not work with older versions of IE

Comment: @Nechehin Worth noting.  But its still a much cleaner solution.

Comment: It's supported since IE9 so is a clean solution for me.

Comment: If you need support for IE8 *and* you're using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org), you could use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind): `this.intervalID = setInterval(_.bind(this.retrieve_rate, this), this.INTERVAL);`

Answer (score 19):

The default behavior of `setInterval` is to bind to the global context. You can call a member function by saving a copy of the current context. Inside retrieve_rate the `this` variable will be correctly bound to the original context. Here is what your code would look like:

```
var self = this;
this.intervalID = setInterval(
    function() { self.retrieve_rate(); },
    this.INTERVAL);
```

Bonus tip: For a plain function reference (as opposed to an object reference which has a member function) you can change the context by using JavaScript's `call` or `apply` methods.

Comment: This worked for me, the call to 'call' doesn't seem to be needed though. The context of retrieve_rate should be set to self by default, because it is called as a member function.

Comment: @Dreendle - you are right, I remembered solving this for a callback function reference where it was needed. I've fixed the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 17):

With improving browser support the time is now good to use the [EcmaScript 6 enhancement, the arrow `=>` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), to preserve `this` properly.

```
startup : function()
    {
        // init prefs
        ...
        this.retrieve_rate();
        this.intervalID = setInterval( () => this.retrieve_rate(), this.INTERVAL);
    },
```

Using => method preserves the `this` when `retrieve_rate()` is called by the interval.  No need for funky self or passing `this` in parameters

Answer (score 10):

`window.setInterval(function(){console.log(this)}.bind(this), 100)`

this is legal in javascript and saves lots of code :)

Answer (score 3):

This would be the cleanest solution, since most of the time you actually want to switch the this context for your consecutive method calls:

Also it's easier to grasp the concept of.

```
    // store scope reference for our delegating method
    var that = this;
    setInterval(function() {
        // this would be changed here because of method scope, 
        // but we still have a reference to that
        OURMETHODNAME.call(that);
    }, 200);
```

Answer (score 3):

With modern browsers the setInterval method allows additional parameters which are passed through to the function specified by func once the timer expires.

[var intervalID = scope.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Hence, a possible solution can be:

```
this.intervalID = setInterval(function (self) {
        self.retrieve_rate();
    }, this.INTERVAL, this);
```

A demo:

```js
var timerId;
document.querySelector('#clickMe').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    timerId = setInterval(function (self) {
        self.textContent = self.textContent.slice(0, -1);
        if (self.textContent.length == 0) {
            clearInterval(timerId);
            self.textContent = 'end..';
        }
    }, 250, this);
})
```

```html
<button id="clickMe">ClickMe</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prefs: null,
startup : function()
    {
        // init prefs
        ...
        this.retrieve_rate();
        var context = this;
        this.intervalID = setInterval(function()
                                      {
                                          context.retrieve_rate();
                                      }, this.INTERVAL);
    },

retrieve_rate : function()
    {
        var ajax = null;
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open('GET', 'http://xyz.example', true);
        var context = this;
        ajax.onload = function()
        {
            // access prefs using context.
            // e.g. context.prefs
        }
    }
```

Comment: `this` inside the function passed to `setInterval`, will refer to the global object. Did you mean `context.retrieve_rate` instead of `this.retrieve_rate` ?

Comment: This has evolved in the right direction, don't need the context being passed as parameter though.

Comment: @Matthew, Anthony
So how do I access it from onload? Tried this.prefs, but didn't work...

Comment: You're welcome Matthew, by the way, you don't need to use `call`, `context.retrieve_rate()` is enough, since you have a *base object* (`context.`)

Comment: Thanks again, @Anthony and @CMS. :)  It's easy to get unnecessarily "clever" when closures are in play.

Comment: Couldn't access it neither with `this` nor with `context`... If you know how exactly, please update the access code.

Comment: @Pablo, `context.prefs` should work in the onload.  I would recommend using a library supporting AJAX (like jQuery), though.

Answer (score -1):

That's not a beauty solution but it's in common usage:

```
var self = this;
var ajax = null;
//...
ajax.onload = function() {
    self.prefs....;
}
```

Comment: The problem is how `setInterval` calls the `retrieve_rate` function, the `this` value inside the method refers to the global object...