# Referencing "this" inside setInterval/setTimeout within object prototype methods

Tags: javascript, scope, lexical-scope

Normally I'd assign an alternative "self" reference when referring to "this" within setInterval. Is it possible to accomplish something similar within the context of a prototype method? The following code errors.

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype = {
    bar: function () {
        this.baz();
    },
    baz: function () {
        this.draw();
        requestAnimFrame(this.baz);
    }
};
```

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749244/javascript-setinterval-and-this-solution

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Unlike in a language like Python, a Javascript method forgets it is a method after you extract it and pass it somewhere else. You can either

### Wrap the method call inside an anonymous function

This way, accessing the `baz` property and calling it happen at the same time, which is necessary for the `this` to be set correctly inside the method call.

You will need to save the `this` from the outer function in a helper variable, since the inner function will refer to a different `this` object.

```
var that = this;
setInterval(function(){
    return that.baz();
}, 1000);
```

### Wrap the method call inside a fat arrow function

In Javascript implementations that implement the [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) feature, it is possible to write the above solution in a more concise manner by using the fat arrow syntax:

```
setInterval( () => this.baz(), 1000 );
```

Fat arrow anonymous functions preserve the `this` from the surrounding function so there is no need to use the `var that = this` trick. To see if you can use this feature, consult a compatibility table like [this one](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-arrow_functions).

### Use a binding function

A final alternative is to use a function such as Function.prototype.bind or an equivalent from your favorite Javascript library.

```
setInterval( this.baz.bind(this), 1000 );

//dojo toolkit example:
setInterval( dojo.hitch(this, 'baz'), 100);
```

Comment: This is a really helpful article about `this` in js: https://dmitripavlutin.com/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript

Comment: 9 years later... The fat arrow function was badass. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i made a proxy class :)

```
function callback_proxy(obj, obj_method_name)
{
    instance_id = callback_proxy.instance_id++;
    callback_proxy.instances[instance_id] = obj;
    return eval('fn = function() { callback_proxy.instances['+instance_id+'].'+obj_method_name+'(); }');
}
callback_proxy.instance_id = 0;
callback_proxy.instances = new Array();

function Timer(left_time)
{
    this.left_time = left_time; //second
    this.timer_id;

    this.update = function()
    {
        this.left_time -= 1;

        if( this.left_time<=0 )
        {
            alert('fin!');
            clearInterval(this.timer_id);
            return;
        }
    }

    this.timer_id = setInterval(callback_proxy(this, 'update'), 1000);
}

new Timer(10);
```