# Second Alert Box "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Referencing “this” inside setInterval/setTimeout within object prototype methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890685/referencing-this-inside-setinterval-settimeout-within-object-prototype-methods)

The second alert box is saying "undefined"? Why is this?

```
<a id = "clickme">Click Me!</a>
<script>
var a = document.getElementById("clickme");
a.onclick = function(); {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
    setTimeout( function() {
        alert( this.innerHTML );
    }, 1000);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because inside the `function` you're passing to `setTimeout`, `this` is not the `a` element anymore. It will either be the `global` object (`window` in browser-land) or `undefined` in strict mode.

Instead, store a reference to `this`;

```
var a = document.getElementById("clickme");
a.onclick = function(); {
    var that = this;

    alert(this.innerHTML);
    setTimeout( function() {
        alert( that.innerHTML );
    }, 1000);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout#The_.22this.22_problem

`this` has a different value inside the `setTimeout` handler.