# 'this' concept in the object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am sorry for that the simple question first. But I just want to know what happen in the code below.

```
var indexobj = {
    test : 1,
    testFunction : function() {
        document.getElementById('AA').innerHTML = indexobj.test++;
        //this is i wanted
        document.getElementById('BB').innerHTML = this.test++;
        //NaN
        setTimeout(indexobj.testFunction,1000);
    },
}
setTimeout(indexobj.testFunction,1);
```

Here is the sample link below

http://jsfiddle.net/apss/JR5Xk/28/

Why in this example the ‘this’ inside the ‘testFunction’ function doesn’t mean ‘indexobj’ this object?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/bind-method-of-javascript

Comment: and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890685/referencing-this-inside-setinterval-settimeout-within-object-prototype-methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `setTimeout` runs callback function in [global object context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout#The_.22this.22_problem), meaning that `indexobj.testFunction` is invoked with `this` being a `window` object.

So you can either do

```
setTimeout(function() {
    indexobj.testFunction();
},1000);
```

or using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create wrapper function with correct context:

```
setTimeout(indexobj.testFunction.bind(indexobj), 1000);
```

Another modern option from ES2015 is to use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that preserves lexical context:

```
setTimeout(() => indexobj.testFunction(), 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

A function's *this* set set by:

1. How the function is called
2. the use of *bind*.

I doesn't matter **where** it's called from.

In this case, you have:

```
setTimeout(indexobj.testFunction,1000);
```

which passes the function referenced by *indexobj.testFunction* to be called later by *setTimeout*. When called, the function is called directly, so its *this* isn't set by the call and it defaults to the global object (window in a browser) or remains undefined in strict mode.

You can fix that in a number of ways, one is to pass a function that sets *indexobj* to *this* in the call:

```
setTimeout(function(){indexobj.testFunction()}, 1000);
```

or you can use *bind* as suggested by dfsq.

Arrow functions in the ES6 draft change how *this* is set, but that's for the next edition…