# ES6 call one method from another

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am new to ES6 syntax, my original code has more implementation, but I have simplified. I am getting an error saying cannot read property 'Method2' of undefined. What am I doing wrong here ? Do I have to do any bind calls.

```
class Class1 {
  constructor() {      
     eventbus.subscribe(this.Method1);  
    }

  Method1() {
   this.Method2(); 
  }

  Method2(){    
  }  
}
```

Comment: Please show all of the relevant code. In JavaScript, most important things happen at *call time*, so show the actual call to `.Method1()`, and some code surrounding it.

Comment: Tell us too how are you running that. With Babel for instance?

Comment: How are you calling `Method1`? JavaScript's invocation contexts are pretty weird: http://codepen.io/vinhnghi223/pen/ghpvt

Comment: The code you've posted [works fine if I imagine what the surrounding/calling code looks like](https://jsfiddle.net/q2s52672/).

Comment: How do you create your object? Your error message say that your object is not instantiated (anymore).

Comment: `new Class1().Method1();` are you doing something like this?

Comment: What's a "private method"?

Comment: This question has been asked a number of times. I'm too lazy right now to find the dup. The classic case is passing a "class' method to `setTimeout`.

Comment: With all due respect, there's no need to see any more code. *How are you calling `Method1`? Obviously, via the `eventbus.subscribe` call.

Comment: I will not close this as dup but this is very close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890685/referencing-this-inside-setinterval-settimeout-within-object-prototype-methods

Comment: See "Common problem: Using object methods as callbacks / event handlers" in the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `eventbus.subscribe(this.Method1.bind(this));`

Since you are associating the method to run on other place, you will be sure under which scope it will run. Forcing the bind to this will assure that is the instance of `Class1` that will be used.

EDIT: Since ES6 allow arrow functions you can also do `eventbus.subscribe(() => this.Method1());`, as it was refereed by @torazaburo

Comment: Personally I would prefer `eventbus.subscribe(() => this.Method1())` now that we have arrow functions.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It will also work. I have edited my answser

Answer (score 2):

> cannot read property 'Method2' of undefined

Most probably you are not creating any object of same class or may be you are missing the `new` keyword to create new object.

```
var cls = Class1(); // will throw error.

cls.Method1();
```

What i meant if you do:

```
var cls = new Class1();

cls.Method1(); // will get executed.
```

[es6fiddle demo.](http://www.es6fiddle.net/ijww5fy2/)

Comment: Direct call is fine, but on callback it loses scope of this. See my edits.

Comment: @anivas see my answer. I think your problem is how you are letting the subscriber call your method.