# difference between (callback) and (() => callback()) in typescript (angular2)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, callback

In vanilla js, this would be the same (not sure anyway..).

The first one :

```
class MyClass {
    myData: Mydata;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.anyService.getAll().then(this.anyMethod)
    }
    anyMethod(data: MyData) {
      this.myData = data;
    }
 }
```

and the compiled js (part with this call is included)

```
this.anyService.getAll().then(this.anyMethod);
```

the call to any method will return an error, but with the second error:

```
class MyClass {
    myData: Mydata;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.anyService.getAll().then(data => this.anyMethod(data))
    }
    anyMethod(data: MyData) {
      this.myData = data;
    }
}
```

and the compiled js:

```
var _this = this;
this.anyService.getAll().then(function () { return _this.anyMethod(); });
```

the conversion

Comment: What is the problem? This question is not at all clear.

Comment: In the first code, `this` in `anyMethod` will not be the `this` you think `this` is - assuming I understand the code and ngOnInit and anyMethod are properties of the same object

Comment: This is an extremely common question which has been answered many times, including [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). Your question title is misleading because it omits the `this` part which is crucial to this issue.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes they are method of the same object, but both `this` in callback aren’t the same ? Because I didn’t scope any one of them in a function.

Comment: no, you didn't, so `this` is clearly not the `this` you think `this` is - because you think it's `this` when in fact it's something else

Comment: @JaromandaX I added compiled js to try to understand more the issue, those are different in vanilla js ? calling this in a function parameter get the parent scope.

Comment: @torazaburo, I couldn’t find an answer in the link you gave me, I don’t see where the error come from..

Comment: Here is a better dup, perhaps someone else can close against this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890685/referencing-this-inside-setinterval-settimeout-within-object-prototype-methods

Comment: thanks @torazaburo i flagged this