# Express.js Cannot read property 'req' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My Express.js app has been throwing `Cannot read property 'req' of undefined`. In essence, it listens for a `GET` request, grab the `content` query, and then reply with a table. Here's the parts that present the problem.

**index.js**

```
var panels = require('./modules/panels.js');
app.get('/panel', function (req, res) {
    var user;
    if (user = req.session.user) {
        panels.getContents(req.query.content, user.innId, res.send);
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
});
```

**modules/panels.js**

```
exports.getContents = function(panelName, innId, callback) {
    var response = "";
    switch (panelName) {
        case 'tenants':
            con.query(queryString, queryParams, function(err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    handle(err);
                } else {
                    if (rows.length == 0) {
                        var tenants = 0;
                        var debtors = 0;
                    } else {
                        var tenants = rows[0].tenants;
                        var debtors = rows[0].length;
                    }
                    response = convertToHTMLTable(rows);
                }
                callback(response); /*THE ERROR POINTS HERE */
            });
            break;

        /* other cases here */

        default:
            response += "Invalid Request";
            callback(response);
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong? My guess is that I'm not suppose to pass `res.send` as a callback. So, how can I fix it?

Comment: did you try to replace `res.send` with `() => res.send()` ?

Comment: `user = req.session.user` should be `user == req.session.user`, exactly what line does throw the error?

Comment: @AdamAzad No, I want to assign the session to the user while checking if it's truthy. I put a comment up there at the erroneous line. it's in panels.js.

Comment: @UlysseBN Yep, looks like that's the problem.

Comment: @starleaf1 A single equals in an if is considered bad practice. Most of the times it happens by mistake so linters will flag it. It can also mislead other developers that look at your code.

Comment: @starleaf1 ok nice, i had a similar issue already : look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40966223/6320039) for more informations about it.

Comment: Now I need some explanation as to why one shouldn't pass a method from one module as a callback to a method from another module.

Comment: @starleaf1 My answer has been up for a while, and seems to be what most people are looking for when they arrive here; would you consider switching it to the accepted answer, so that people don't get lost in the wall of code in the currently accepted answer and move on before they see mine below? It also resolves your "Note to future reads" problem. Further, I believe it answers your question from January 23rd 2017 here. Cheers!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I also experienced this error, and after chewing on the error message for a bit and staring at my code for too long, It clicked.

I (and the asker above) had code that looked like this:

```
  somethingAsync
  .then(res.send) // <-- storing send() divorced from parent object "res"
}
```

The problem is that when res.send gets called later, it is divorced from its dynamic scope--which means that calls to `this` inside of the `send` method, which would normally refer to `res`, now refer to `global`. Evidently, `res.send` contains a reference to `this.req`, given the error message.

An equivalent scenario:

```
res = {
    send: function() { 
        console.log(this.originalMessage.req);
    },
    originalMessage: { req: "hello SO" },
};

res.send();
// # "hello SO"
const x = {};
x.send = res.send;
x.send();
// # Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'req' of undefined
```

Or, to put it another way:

```
new Promise(_ => _())
.then(_ => console.log(this.msg.req));
// # Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'req' of undefined
```

**Two solutions:**

```
handler(req, res) {
  somethingAsync
  .then(() => res.send())
   // ^ send will be called as a method of res, preserving dynamic scope
   // that is, we're storing a function that, when called, calls
   // "res.send()", instead of storing the "send" method of "res" by itself.
}
```

And a theoretically more idiomatic approach is

```
handler(req, res) {
  somethingAsync
  .then(res.send.bind(res))
  //^ res is explicitly bound to the saved function as its dynamic scope
}
```

Pernicious little gotcha of dynamic scoping, that one. Seems like express should ditch the dynamic scoping there, or at least throw a better error...

Comment: Just had this issue as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try this in **index.js**

```
panels.getContents(req.query.content, user.innId, res);
```

and into panels.js

```
exports.getContents = function(panelName, innId, response) {
    var response = "";
    switch (panelName) {
        case 'tenants':
            con.query(queryString, queryParams, function(err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    handle(err);
                } else {
                    if (rows.length == 0) {
                        var tenants = 0;
                        var debtors = 0;
                    } else {
                        var tenants = rows[0].tenants;
                        var debtors = rows[0].length;
                    }
                    response.send(convertToHTMLTable(rows));
                }
            });
            break;

        /* other cases here */

        default:
            error += "Invalid Request";
            response.send(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note to future readers: There are modifications that I must do before this answer worked, but I can't edit this without revealing too much of my code.

Answer (score 2):

When you passed `res.send` as an argument to the `getContents` function (`panels.getContents(req.query.content, user.innId, res.send);`) it is passed in a new variable and you called it `callback`.

So `res.send` is now stripped from it's original/supposed-to-be `lexical context`/`binding`
which is the `res` object in this case, and it appears that `res.send` uses the `req` property in the `res` object using `this.req`.

What you've done here is unintentionally changing the value of `this` for the function `send` to be the global object.

#### Solution

there are two ways to fix this problem

- `panels.getContents(req.query.content, user.innId, () => res.send);`

// OR

- `panels.getContents(req.query.content, user.innId, res.send.bind(res));`

in the second solution, you bind the function `res.send` to always treat any value of `this` to be the `res` object (`bind it to the res object`)