# Calling setInterval within an object, overrides "this"

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a code to perform a "watch" on some resource in an api : 
Considering my code :

```
function myObj(){
   this.endpoint  = "/example"; // my endpoint
   this.interval = 500; // my watch interval
}

myObj.prototype.watch = function(){
   console.log(this.endpoint); // returns "/example"
   this.intervalId = setInterval(this.refresh, this.interval);
}

myObj.prototype.destroy= function(){
   clearInterval(this.intervalId);
}

myObj.prototype.refresh = function(){

   console.log(this.endpoint) // -> undefined ??? 

}
```

Comment: You lose scope of `this` inside the interval, `bind()` it

Comment: `setInterval(this.refresh.bind(this), this.interval)`

Comment: Its a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890685/referencing-this-inside-setinterval-settimeout-within-object-prototype-methods @Patrick Evans

Comment: start constructor function name with a capital letter (it has nothing to do with your problem but this is a convention)

Comment: sure @EngineerPassion Thanks

Comment: It's either one, you are trying to use a class method as a callback, and losing execution context. The one I linked is more informative.