# How to clear an interval set in this particular way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working in react. I want to clear my interval on componentWillUnmount

The interval is set as this

```
setInterval( () => this.baz(), 1000 );
```

Following this answer here [Referencing "this" inside setInterval/setTimeout within object prototype methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890685/referencing-this-inside-setinterval-settimeout-within-object-prototype-methods)

How do I clear that. I am sorry if this is a basic question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save a reference to the [intervalID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Return_value) on the component (`this.intervalID`), and clear it in componentWillUnmount:

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalID = setInterval( () => this.baz(), 1000 );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
  }

  render() {
    //...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` returns an ID when you call it. You simply need to save that and pass it to `clearInterval()`. You can very easily save that in your state:

```
this.setState({ intervalId: setInterval(() => this.baz(), 1000) });
```

And then in `componentWillUnmount()`:

```
clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
```