# Recursively referencing a function in Node Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have the below code where I am trying to recursively `console.log` the counter with a `setTimeout`. I was working on two versions, but I am getting errors for each.

In the first one I am not sure why `setTimeout` does not see `this.timeTest` as a function.

In second I understand that `this.timeTest` is outside of scope. 
Is there a way to get it into scope?

Server

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const time = require('./timeoutFun.js')

time.timeTest()

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Attempt 1

```
const time = {
    counter: 0,
    timeTest: function() {
        this.counter++
        console.log(this.counter)
        if (this.counter < 5) {
            this.timeTest()
        } else if (this.counter === 10) {
            console.log("done")
        } else {
            setTimeout(this.timeTest(), 3000);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = time;
```

Attempt 2

```
const time = {
    counter: 0,
    timeTest: function() {
        this.counter++
        if (this.counter < 5) {
            console.log("start")
            console.log(this.counter)
            this.timeTest()
        } else if (this.counter === 10) {
            console.log("done")
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("wait")
                console.log(this.counter)
                this.timeTest()
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = time;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890685/referencing-this-inside-setinterval-settimeout-within-object-prototype-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you're passing the *result* of calling the `timeTest` function, rather than *the function itself*, i.e.:

```
setTimeout(this.timeTest(), 3000); // wrong
setTimeout(this.timeTest, 3000);   // right
```

As for the second example, `this.timeTest` is indeed out of scope because introducing the anonymous function in the `setTimeout` invocation creates a new "context", by which I mean a new value for `this`. In javascript, if you want to replace the default context assigned to the anonymous function, you can use the context binding function [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

That's a little complex for newbies to javascript, and there's no need to do that here - just fix the first example as above and it will work as intended.

But for posterity, this is how you'd fix the second example:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("wait")
    console.log(this.counter)
    this.timeTest()
}.bind(this), 3000); // note the bind invocation here
```

You can also use what's known as [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which, instead of assigning the function body a new context, assigns it the context of the enclosing scope (note this is only available in ES6).

```
setTimeout(() => { // no need for manual binding
    console.log("wait")
    console.log(this.counter)
    this.timeTest()
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

`setTimeout(this.timeTest(), 3000)`

to this:

`setTimeout(this.timeTest, 3000)`

`setTimeout` takes a `Function` as it's first argument. You are passing the result of that function as the 1st argument, instead of the Function itself.