# Cannot read property of undefined when calling the function with setInterval in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

When calling a function without any problem,but when  call it in setInterval so  keep calling it each second it gives me the error: cannot read property of undefined on the service!

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,private 
 conversationService:ConversationService) {
 }


 ngOnInit() {
 this.sender = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("username");
 this.receiver = sessionStorage.getItem("username");
 setInterval(
 function()
 { 
   this.conversationService.
   getTheConversation(this.receiver,this.sender).subscribe(
     data=>this.result=data)
   },1000);
 }
```

error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTheConversation' of undefined

Comment: why not use rxjs Timer? some like `timer(0,1000).pipe(switchMap(()=>{return this.conversationService.getTheConversation(this.receiver,this.sender)})).subscribe(data=>this.result=data)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 ngOnInit() {
 this.sender = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("username");
 this.receiver = sessionStorage.getItem("username");
 setInterval(()=>
 { 
   this.conversationService.
   getTheConversation(this.receiver,this.sender).subscribe(
     data=>this.result=data)
   },1000);
 }
```

use **fat arrow** `=>` to maintain `this` scope. When you declare a new `function` , it creates it's own `this`.

Comment: You can use 'rxjs' Timer and switchMap too.

Answer (score 2):

The function setInterval is referring to a different **this** object,

The correct way to do this would be,

```
const newThis = this;
setInterval(
 function()
 { 
   newThis.conversationService.
   getTheConversation(newThis.receiver,newThis.sender).subscribe(
     data=>newThis.result=data)
   },1000);
```

Follow the link for more other ways of doing it https://stackoverflow.com/a/7890978/11914056