# Cannot read property in setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, setinterval

On node.js I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'talk_duration' of undefined
```

From: `setTimeout(this.hangup, this.data.talk_duration * 1000);` in the `setInterval`.

However, outside of `setInterval` I have `console.log(this.data.talk_duration);` which work fine.

```
this.outcomeAnswer = function () {

    console.log(this.data.talk_duration); //this work

    num = 0;

    db.run("INSERT INTO in_queue (action_id, state) VALUES ('" + this.data.action_id + "', 'InQueue')", function (error) {
        queueCheckLoop = setInterval(function () {

            num++;

            if (num == 5) {
                clearInterval(queueCheckLoop);
            }

            db.each("SELECT count(*) as total FROM agent_queue WHERE state = 'Ready'", function (err, row) {
                if (row.total > 0) {
                    clearInterval(queueCheckLoop);
                    setTimeout(this.hangup, this.data.talk_duration * 1000);
                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: I suspect `this` isn't what you think it is. your existing console.logs seem to confirm that.

Comment: There has *got* to be a canonical question we can link this to. Got to be.

Comment: There is a dupe for this specific question though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749244/javascript-setinterval-and-this-solution?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remember `this` right as the top line in your oucomeAnswer function, e.g.:
`var that=this;`

Then use 
`that.data.talk_duration` in functions with different scope.