# Why does my method print "Seconds: NAN"

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am having trouble debugging the increment and tick methods of my Clock class. The seconds property of Clock should be incremented by 1 every second, but instead seconds is throwing a NaN error.

The goal of increment is to increment the seconds on the Clock instance by 1 each time it is called. Tick calls the increment method every second to make this possible.

```
function Clock() {
  this.seconds = 0;
}

Clock.prototype.increment = function() {
  this.seconds = this.seconds + 1;
  console.log('Seconds: ' + this.seconds);
};

Clock.prototype.tick = function() {
  setInterval(this.increment, 1000);
};

var timex = new Clock();

timex.tick();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that within your `setInterval` handler, `this` no longer points to your `Clock` object, but to the global namespace. The easiest solution is just to bind `this` to `this.increment`:

```
Clock.prototype.tick = function() {
  setInterval(this.increment.bind(this), 1000);
};
```

See also: [Javascript setInterval and `this` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749244/javascript-setinterval-and-this-solution)

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions. Just vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Just voted to close, but it's easier for the OP to also have a solution.

Comment: ...which they'd get from the duplicate. Or, for that matter, a simple comment. By answer the question, you reduce the possibility of deleting the question.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the window when you call it with setTimeout.

```
setInterval(this.increment.bind(this), 1000);
```