# stopping a js interval for an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, intervals

can anyone tell me why this code doesn't work the way I expect it to?

```
function npc(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.grid = [[0,9], [0,9]];
  this.position = [0,0];
  this.start = setInterval(function(){this.move() }, 1000);
  this.stop = function(){clearInterval(this.start)};
  this.move = function() {
      this.position[0] = this.position[0] + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
      this.position[1] = this.position[1] + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
      if (this.position[0] > this.grid[0][1] || this.position[1] > this.grid[1[1]) {
      this.position = [0,0];
  };
  console.log(this.name + " moved to " + this.position);  
  }
};

npc();
var bug = new npc("test-name");
bug.start();
bug.stop();
```

Bug.start() won't run unless I do npc() first, but even then it logs undefined as name and won't stop using the bug.stop()

Sorry if this is basic stuff, but I just can't work this out on my own...

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). `this` can be easy to mess up, especially without arrow functions. `this` in a function called with `setInterval`/`setTimeout` is not what you would expect.

Comment: note that `bug.start()` doesn't run at all ever, cause it isn't a function, it is a number.  it is the number that results when you call `setInterval`.  Now the interval does start, but that is a result of your calling `npc()` and new `npc("test-name")` :).  in this code, `bug.stop()` will never get called because `bug.start()` is an error that stops execution.  There's a number of solutions below that solve the problem you're asking about (including mine ;).  but pointing out ANOTHER error in the code above.

Comment: Yes I understand it now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
function npc(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.grid = [[0,9], [0,9]];
  this.position = [0,0];
  var that=this;
  this.start = setInterval(function(){that.move() }, 1000);
  this.stop = function(){clearInterval(this.start)};
  this.move = function() {
      this.position[0] = this.position[0] + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
      this.position[1] = this.position[1] + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
      if (this.position[0] > this.grid[0][1] || this.position[1] > this.grid[1[1]]) {
      this.position = [0,0];
  };
  console.log(this.name + " moved to " + this.position);  
  }
}
```

this changes context inside setInterval.

just after this function Definition
Call

```
var bug = new npc("test-name");
```

It shows some console O/p like 
test-name moved to 1,0
test-name moved to 2,0

Comment: I like this solution. What about the clearInterval part? It still doesn't work...

Comment: @user7841242 bug.stop() stops the console's.. sorry what doesnt work ?

Comment: @user7841242 No problem :) u can accept as answer & UpVote it :D

Comment: @ArthurCinader : no need, this will work there, because we aren't writting it inside a function.

Comment: While this works, I am getting `bug.start is not a function error` when I run this script. I think this.start definition needs to be wrapped inside a function.

Comment: @jrook yes I get the same error. how can i make sure i can start and stop 'bug' whenever i want?

Comment: @ParthGhiya:  since you have changed other parts of the OP's code, I suggest applying all those changes to the formatted section of your answer. I mean this: `var bug = new npc("test-name");`

Comment: @jrook, you don't need to call bug.start().  just instantiating npc will start the interval.  start() isn't a function, it is the return value from setInterval which is a number that represents the interval

Comment: @ArthurCinader, I know that. As I said, it is more of a formatting issue.

Comment: @user7841242: What do you mean by `whenever`? Do you require some conditions or a time interval to be passed? In that case ,please edit your question to include these requirements.

Comment: @user7841242 : if you want time interval, then you will need one more parameter. whenever you will create an object of bug it will start & Whenever u will call stop method, it will stop.

Comment: I want it to start on start method and stop on stop method. I've wrapped stop in a function 'this.start = function() {setInterval(function(){that.move() }, 1000); console.log(this.name + " started.") };'  but now the stop method isnt working...

Comment: Ok, now I see. I was trying to stop not the interval, but the function. Thanks for the help everybody :)

Answer (score 1):

While the given solutions work correctly, there is another solution which uses the idea introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749244/javascript-setinterval-and-this-solution):

You will only need to change `start` variable like this:

```
this.start = function() {
setInterval(
  (function(self) {
  return function() {
    self.move();
    }
   })(this), 1000);
}
```

To demonstrate how you can use `start()` and `stop()` functions using this method, I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uyynvrzh/). Note that you can both stop by clicking a button or by defining some condition inside your `setInterval()` function.

For example, if you want to stop the bug if it the second position hits 1:

```
this.handle; //To keep timer handle
this.start = function() {
this.handle = setInterval(
    (function(self) {
    return function() {
      self.move();
      if(self.position[1]==1) self.stop(self.handle); //Stop on some condition   
      }
    })(this), 1000);
  };
  this.stop = function(handle) {
      console.log("time to stop");
      clearInterval(handle);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is with what `this` is at various points in your code.  `setInterval` is a function on the `window` object, so `this` is a reference to `window`.  But don't take my word for it!   `console.log(this)` and see for yourself!

The solution below is one way to solve the issue.  Note setting `this` to `that`.  As well as binding `bug` to this.....

```
<script>
  var Npc = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.grid = [[0,9], [0,9]];
    this.position = [0,0];
  }

  Npc.prototype.start = function() {
    if(this.interval) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    this.interval = setInterval(function(that) {
      that.move();
    }, 100, this);
  }


  Npc.prototype.stop = function() {
    if(this.interval) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
  }

  Npc.prototype.move = function() {
    this.position[0] = this.position[0] + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    this.position[1] = this.position[1] + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    if (this.position[0] > this.grid[0][1] || this.position[1] > this.grid[1][1]) {
      this.position = [0,0];
    };
    console.log(this.name + " moved to " + this.position);
  }


  var bug = new Npc("test-name");
  bug.start();
  setInterval(bug.stop.bind(bug), 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: This is too complex for me ;/

Comment: :).  well, you put "object" in the question title, so I was trying to show you how to explicitly make npc behave like an object.  above, you ask how to start and stop.  this solution solves that too.  fwiw ;).