# Repeat function failed in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, repeat

For my Angular Project, I generated a geolocation component and want to repeat a function `findMe()` to show the current location.

Part of code in the *component.ts* is given as below.

```
...
export class GeolocationComponent implements OnInit{
 @ViewChild('gmap') gmapElement: any;
 map: google.maps.Map;
 isTracking = false;
 marker: google.maps.Marker;

 constructor(public globalvar: GlobalvarService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   var mapProp = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.542211, 153.1226333),
     zoom: 15,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
   this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);

   setInterval(this.findMe(), 3000);

 }

 findMe() {
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
       this.showPosition(position);
       console.log("find me");
     });
   } else {
     alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
   }
 }

 showPosition(position) {
   this.globalvar.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
   this.globalvar.longitude = position.coords.longitude;

   let location = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
   this.map.panTo(location);

   if (!this.marker) {
     this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: location,
       map: this.map,
       title: 'Got you!'
     });
   }
   else {
     this.marker.setPosition(location);
   }
 }
 ...
```

In

```
ngOnInit(),
```

I use

```
setInterval(this.findMe(), 3000);
```

By checking the log, I see the `findMe()` is only called once, but not be repeated as that I expect.

I also tried changing `findMe()` ==> `findMe`

```
setInterval(this.findMe, 3000);
```

this time, the log repeatedly appears, however there is always a error:

`ERROR TypeError: _this.showPosition is not a function`

Could you please help how can I repeatedly calling `findMe()` and why the error happens?

Comment: I have only showPosition() as given in above code. findMe() function call this function using this.showPostion().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to invoke the interval is with the function declaration `setInterval(this.findMe, 3000);`. As you noted, if you include the () it is only executed once.

One of the issues that comes up with setInterval is that it changes the `this` context of the executing function. To fix this, you need to force it to be constant.

```
constructor(public globalvar: GlobalvarService) {
  this.findMe = this.findMe.bind(this);
}
```

---

Additional info:

- [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)
- [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749244/javascript-setinterval-and-this-solution)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an arrow function that preserves `this` context :

```
setInterval(() => this.findMe(), 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrow function syntax to make it work.

```
ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.findMe()
    }, 4000);
}

findMe = () => {
    console.log('found');
}
```

Arrow function is referencing this as Component at all times.

Example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wkv2he

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 setInterval(() => {
    this.findMe()
 }, 3000);
```

But I think than better solution is to use Observable interval.

```
interval(3000).subscribe(res => {
   this.findMe()
})
```

Or in older versions of Angular :)

```
Observable.interval(3000).subscribe(res => {
   this.findMe()
})
```