# Call a function inside another function in javascript classes

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```js
/* MY CLASS */
class Cronometer{
    constructor(){
    }

    getKey(key){
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('taskRunning'))[key];
    }

    initCronometer(currentTask){
        var startDate = new Date().getTime();

        var config = {
            "startDate": startDate,
            "currentTask": currentTask
        };

        localStorage.setItem('taskRunning', JSON.stringify(config));
       

        var idInterval = setInterval(function(){
            var time = this.convertToTime( new Date().getTime() - this.getKey('startDate') );
            console.log(time);
        }, 1000);

        return idInterval;
    }

}

/* RUN */
var c = new Cronometer();
c.initCronometer(5555);
```

when I run the **c.initCronometer(5555)**, I receive this message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.getKey is not a function
```

Somebody can tell me why that error is showing?

Comment: Put the error message in the question, not an image of it....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749244/javascript-setinterval-and-this-solution

Comment: get rid of the `this` keyword, which is no longer referencing the class scope because its inside a callback function when being called.

Comment: you may use setInterval additional param: setInterval(function(obj){....obj.getKey('startDate') );}, 1000, this);

Comment: The value of /this/ inside your callback won't be bound to your instance when the callback is actually invoked. You could use the arrow-function syntax (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0):

Change your Interval code to the following:

```
 var idInterval = setInterval(() => {
        var time = this.convertToTime( new Date().getTime() - this.getKey('startDate') );
        console.log(time);
    }, 1000);
```

You should use arrow functions in such cases to not loose the context(“this” pointer).

When using usual function(anonymous functions) they create a new “this” inside themselves.